# Matplotlib 3.5.2 not plotting as expected

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder, miniconda

In a fresh Python install (Miniconda3, for details see below), Matplotlib 3.5.2 is not plotting as it used to:

Example 1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y1 = np.sin(2*pi*x)
y2 = np.cos(2*pi*x)

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
```

This gives me the first plot (x, y1), but not the second (x, y2)

Example 2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y1 = np.sin(2*pi*x)
y2 = np.cos(2*pi*x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1)
```

This doesn't plot anything at all, but only produces an empty plot.

In both cases, `plt.show()` doesn't help. Also, I'm not getting any errors or warnings. Plotting both functions in one go (`plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2)`) does work, by the way.

Installation details:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Miniconda 3
Python 3.9.13
Spyder 5.3.1, with backend set to Automatic (opens plots in separate window)
Matplotlib 3.5.2
```

Both examples used to work just fine in my old install (Ubuntu 20.04, Miniconda 3, Python 3.7.12, Matplotlib 3.4.3, Spyder 5.1.5).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT:

- Also commands like `plt.xlim([0, 0.5])` do not have any effect
- Running the first example script in one go, instead of line by line from the iPython console, does give the expected result (i.e. a blue sine and an orange cosine). This doesn't work for the second script though.
- After manually interacting with the plot window, e.g. by clicking in the plot area and pressing `g` (to toggle grid display), the most recent change to the plot suddenly appears, so it looks like something's wrong with the interaction between the iPython console and the plot window

Comment: Try [changing the backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`. A dependency may be at fault for the current outcome

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Changing the backend to inline gives me two separate plots in the Spyder Plots pane (which is as expected as far as I know), but after changing back to Automatic (I'd really like to have my plots in a separate window), I'm getting the same behaviour as described above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem is related to Matplotlib 3.5.2. For now, I've downgraded to my previous Matplotlib version, 3.4.3.